# Как получить знак "чистка"?

Tags: обсуждение, правки, знаки

В описании написано, что необходимо выполнить откат. Что имеется в виду под этим?

Comment: Откат карается ст. 159 ук рф

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, я не про денежный откат )

Comment: Добавил иллюстрацию, используя в качестве примера ваш вопрос )

Comment: @NickVolynkin, спасибо)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Каждое редактирование сообщения (вопроса или ответа) сохраняется в истории. (Последовательные правки от одного автора в пределах 5 минут объединяются в одну версию.)

Сообщение можно вернуть к одной из предыдущих версий. Это действие и называется "откат сообщения". Оно создает новую правку, которая тоже сохраняется в истории.

Делать это стоит только тогда, когда очередная правка испортила сообщение, чтобы вернуть его к хорошему состоянию. Такие случаи не очень часты. Вероятно, потому за это и дается знак.

**Пример (кликабельный, ведёт на реальную страницу истории):**

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А нет ли возможности добавить краткое описание данного знака из этого поста к [справке по знакам](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges) (вроде у других знаков более-менее развернетое описание по сравнению с этим)? До прочтения данного поста я тоже понятия не имел за что именно дается этот знак и думаю, что не я один.