# Редактирование описания знака «Чистка»?

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено

Хотелось бы внести предложение, по редактированию описания знака «[**Чистка**](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/4/cleanup)». Дело в том, что в описании указано следующее:

> *Первый откат*

До того момента, пока я не наткнулся на этот вопрос:  «**[Как получить знак “чистка”?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2506/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0?rq=1)**», я понятия не имел, как получить этот знак, и что за откат нужно сделать. Комментарий от [@АлексейШиманский](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/191482/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%A8%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9) в том вопросе очень повеселил. Спасибо [@NickVolynkin♦](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/181472/nick-volynkin), за предоставленный ответ, без него и правда не разобраться. По такому случаю, думаю, что будет уместным изменить описание знака.

Comment: Пожалуйста. Согласен, без подробностей "откат" звучит как-то очень коррупционно.

Comment: Применил новое описание.

Comment: @NickVolynkin не забудьте пнуть Николая для подхватывания БД.

Comment: @alexolut, это видимо поэтому пока не видно изменений?

Comment: @DenisBubnov в частности.

Comment: @alexolut полгода спокойно подождали, незачем теперь спешить. ))

Comment: @NickVolynkin тогда давайте вешать [meta-tag:статус-завершено], когда изменение уже вступило в силу. Ну или добавлять соответствующий комментарий о том, когда оно вступит в силу. Иначе это порождает лишние вопросы.

Comment: @alexolut не согласен. Я не хочу держать в памяти, что нужно вернуться к этому вопросу и поставить метку. Если изменения утверждены, они неизбежно попадут на прод, сегодня ли, завтра ли. Вреда тоже не вижу от того, что строка до сих пор не поменялась.

Comment: @alexolut читайте описание метки [meta-tag:завершено]: "Метка добавляется в тот момент, когда запрошенные изменения включаются в очередную версию исходного кода сайта. Однако, они могут быть приведены в действие не сразу, а в течение 24 часов. Это обусловлено механизмом работы сайта. Если ваш вопрос был обозначен этой меткой, но фактических изменений пока что нет, подождите не менее суток."

Comment: @NickVolynkin транзифекс сам не подтягивается, так что и 24 часа не хватит, если Николас не подтянет базу.

Comment: @NickVolynkin прошло более суток. Предложение фактически не реализовано не смотря на наличие метки [meta-tag:статус-завершено]. Что можете сказать в своё оправдание?

Comment: @alexolut только то, что я не обязан оправдываться. Если хотите, чтобы я проставлял метку точно в момент деплоя строк, вам придётся платить мне зарплату.

Comment: @NickVolynkin Вы считаете, что делать правильно можно только за зарплату?

Comment: @alexolut я считаю, что я уже всё делаю правильно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Предлагаю такой вариант:

> Первый откат сообщения к предыдущей версии

Comment: я вообще за любое редактирование, которое внесет ясность :)

Comment: Некоторую неясность вносит определение "предыдущей версии". Т.к. судя по всему знак выдается за откат к любой версии.

Comment: ... к одной из предыдущих версий.

Comment: @alexolut, откат будет произведен к любой версии, которая является по определению предыдущей. К будущей не откатить же? :) Поэтому тогда "предыдущая" уместна.

Comment: @DenisBubnov уместность, граничащая с излишеством.

Comment: @alexolut, возможно. Тогда Ваш вариант *Первый откат сообщения* - мне нравится, но в нем не хватает слова *изменений* :)

Comment: Так когда внедрим?)

Comment: @Vadizar не прошло и полгода. :) Спасибо за напоминание, применил вариант.

Comment: @NickVolynkin спасибо) Наконец-то понятное объяснение) Ждем массовое получение знаков)

Comment: @Vadizar так уже 193 штуки http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/4/cleanup

Answer (score 2):

> Первый откат сообщения к более ранней версии

Comment: А можно откатить не к более ранней? Т.е. подкатить :)

Comment: @alexolut, идея была в убирании слова "предыдущей" из соседнего ответа.

Comment: Убирание - это хорошо. Но вот получилась замена.

Comment: @alexolut, я замену и имел в виду. С чистым убиранием тут твой вариант уже есть. Это ж голосование :)

Comment: Тот вариант для полноты картины, лично я больше склоняюсь к тому, чтобы вообще ничего не менять (тоже есть такой ответ).

Answer (score 0):

Первый вариант:

> Первый откат изменения сообщения

Думал, что можно и без слова ***сообщения***, но действие относится именно к сообщению, поэтому это слово должно присутствовать в описании.

Comment: Чтобы можно было голосовать каждый вариант следует оформить в виде отдельного ответа.

Comment: @alexolut, хорошо, сейчас сделаю

Answer (score 0):

Третий вариант:

> Первый откат правки сообщения

Answer (score 0):

**Оставить как есть.**

На enSO [описание](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/4/cleanup) метки тоже простое, и тоже имеется [вопрос](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17038/what-is-a-rollback) о том, что же это такое. Считаю, что не стоит усложнять описание там, где этого можно избежать. В случае чего можно поискать по Мете или задать новый вопрос.

Comment: Не думаю, что описание метки будет усложнено, за счет добавления нескольких слов в это описание. Что приведет к ясности и не будет вызывать вопросов. Думаю, что русскоязычный SO в силу *ширины* именно русского языка нуждается в некоторых уточнениях.

Comment: @DenisBubnov на самом деле термин "откат" вполне себе очевиден в контексте работы с системой контроля версий, которая по сути и реализуется в движке SO при редактировании сообщений.

Answer (score 0):

Вариант в качестве альтернативы:

> Первый откат сообщения